# Remove duplicates from my SQL query results

Tags: sql, distinct

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MovieAttributes.Description),
    MDetails.AttributeValueID, MovieAtrVal.Value
FROM 
    MDetails 
INNER JOIN 
    MovieAtrVal ON MovieAtrVal.AtrValID = MDetails.AttributeValueID
INNER JOIN 
    MovieAttributes ON MovieAttributes.ID = MovieAtrVal.AtrID 
WHERE 
    MovieID IN (SELECT Movie.ID 
                FROM Movie 
                INNER JOIN Subjects ON Subjects.ID = Movie.SubjectID 
                WHERE Subjects.Name LIKE '308') 
    AND MovieAttributes.Description != 'Environment'
```

And the output is something like this:

```
RoadInfrastructure      1   None
Hairstyle               5   Short hair
Weather                 8   Sunny
Glasses                 18  Corrective glasses
Beard                   28  No beard
Age                     31  Young (17 to 35)
Age                     32  Middle (36 to 55)
RoadType                34  City
Accessories             38  None
Makeup                  44  None
FacialFeatures          47  None
RoadType                177 None
Weather                 178 Artificial light
Seating_height          206 83
Display_distance        220 67
```

I want sth witohut 2x age, 2x RoadType and 2xWeather

I think that I should use DISTINCT but in this case didn't work.

Comment: And of course you researched your problem, and found the 100's of questions asking this same thing. Why didn't those solutions work for you?

Comment: `DISTINCT` in SQL only works on the **whole row** - not a single column. None of your complete rows are duplicates

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use distinct but get the the top rows over partition by description ordered by attributevalueid

```
WITH aux AS (
    SELECT
        movieattributes.description,
        mdetails.attributevalueid,
        movieatrval.value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY movieattributes.description
            ORDER BY
                mdetails.attributevalueid
        ) rn
    FROM
        mdetails
        INNER JOIN movieatrval ON movieatrval.atrvalid = mdetails.attributevalueid
        INNER JOIN movieattributes ON movieattributes.id = movieatrval.atrid
    WHERE
        movieid IN (
            SELECT
                movie.id
            FROM
                movie
                INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.id = movie.subjectid
            WHERE
                subjects.name LIKE '308'
        )
        AND movieattributes.description != 'Environment'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aux
WHERE
    rn = 1
```